# What references are there to black holes in Star Trek TV shows?

Tags: star-trek

Other than the *TOS* black star, the naked singularity of the Romulan engines, and the *Enterprise* episode "Singularity", were there other references to black holes in any of the *Star Trek* TV shows?

Comment: Are you interested in only the TV shows, or do movies count as well? And what exactly counts as a "black hole" for your question? Do the characters need to literally use the words "black hole", or would objects like the Quantum Singularity from the second episode of Voyager (which looks and behaves _nothing_ like a real black hole) count as well?

Comment: Just the TV shows.  Any reference to a singularity that warps space-time to the point where the escape velocity exceeds C.

Comment: Why don't you check Memory Alpha? One such reference is made by the disgruntled (human) Q in "Deja Q."

Comment: Didn't know that was something that could be searched. Thanks.

Comment: Uh... I am not recalling the "black star" reference from *TOS*... anyone got an episode reference?

Comment: "Tomorrow is Yesterday"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interestingly, the term "black hole" seems to be mostly abandoned by the 23rd century, according to Commander Deckard in Star Trek: The Motion Picture

> DECKARD: Captain, Voyager 6 disappeared into what **they used to call a black hole**.

This perhaps explains why the term "black hole" is encountered so infrequently throughout TOS, TNG, DS9, and Voyager, despite frequent references to seemingly similar phenomena. However, there have been a few nominal references to black holes throughout the later TV series:

- In TNG "[Deja Q](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deja_Q_(episode))", Q hypothesizes that a moon's orbit was destabilized by a black hole. No such object is ever seen, however.
- In TNG "[Timescape](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Timescape_(episode))" Data concludes that a species of alien uses black holes are "nests." Again, they only mentioned, not seen.
- In VOY "[Hunters](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hunters_(episode))", Kim and Paris refer to a quantum singularity being used as a space station's power source as a black hole:

> KIM: Commander, if my sensors are right, that station is using a quantum singularity as a power source.
>
> PARIS: A black hole?
>
> KIM: It's a tiny one, probably about a centimetre in diameter, but it's putting out almost four terawatts of energy.

Additional references to the object as a "black hole" later in the episode confirm that Paris's nomenclature is at least informally correct. Furthermore, this marks the only time in the series where we see a black hole "in action" when the singularity's containment fails and it destroys the station and two Hirogen vessels.

[image: the station begins to collapse inwards as white light radiates from its center]
[image: a hirogen vessel begins to explode as it falls towards a swirling blue disk with a black spot at the center]

Now that we have established that "quantum singularity" is a synonym for "black hole", we can also include the object from VOY "[Parallax](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Parallax_(episode))", which possessed an event horizon and trapped Voyager inside it. As Voyager was unable to leave the event horizon even at warp velocities, this probably meets your criterion of having an escape velocity greater than *c*.

The series are replete with references to other varieties of [singularity](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Singularity), but none resemble black holes as we understand the term.

Comment: Shockingly, they got that part right: smaller black holes actually emit more power due to Hawking radiation.

Answer (score 3):

- In *The Motion Picture*, Voyager 6 is said to have disappeared into "what they used to call a black hole", although given that it was spat out elsewhere in the galaxy it seems more like a wormhole (at least as the term is used in other Trek media).
- "Singularity" is also used to refer to the aperture of a wormhole or similar "tunnel" on several other occasions in DS9 and *Voyager*.
- In *The Next Generation* 3x13 "Deja Q" (the one where Q is turned human), there's a passing reference to a black hole having caused the disaster of the week when it passed through the system, destabilizing the orbit of an inhabited planet's moon.
- Also in *The Next Generation* are the Romulan ship engines, which run on contained singularities as you mentioned. The Hirogen also used this technology at least once, in *Voyager* 4x15 "Hunters"; *Voyager* disrupted the containment field around the singularity, causing it to explode into a black hole.
- *Voyager* also encountered a kind-of-but-not-really black hole-like "singularity" in 1x03 "Parallax" which they were trapped in for awhile.
- As you mentioned, in *Enterprise* 2x09 "Singularity" the Enterprise encounters a trinary system where one of the stars is a black hole, and runs into problems while trying to survey it.
- In *Star Trek*, the JJ Abrams reboot, black holes generated from "red matter" are used as a doomsday weapon.
- In *Discovery* 2x08 "If Memory Serves" there's a *fake* black hole, used as a deterrent to entering the Talos system.

Aside from a handful of uses as a generic space hazard ("Singularity", "Parallax") or as a volatile power source ("Hunters", several uses by the Romulans, the reboot movie) black holes don't seem to have made much impression on the franchise, perhaps because by definition they don't really *do* anything aside from mindlessly threaten our protagonists.

Answer (score 1):

Does a Ferengi drink called a *'[black hole](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Black_hole_(beverage))'* count as a reference to black holes?

We see one in *DS9: Playing God*

[image]

Comment: I was interested in references to a singularity that warps space-time to the point where the escape velocity exceeds C.

Answer (score 0):

In TOS the black hole was referred to as a "Black Planet", in the episode The Arena. Perhaps the term black hole was too new to the mainstream media to be taken seriously.

Comment: I don't see any mention of a "black planet" in [the transcript for "Arena"](http://chakoteya.net/StarTrek/19.htm).